# Increase the number of rows in sql

Tags: sql, select

I am learning SQL. I have a Select-From command and the output result is limited to 25 rows. I would like to increase the number of rows to say 50 or 75 rows displayed. What syntax do I include in my Select - From code to make this possible?

I tried typing 50 in front of the Select * Command.

Comment: How is "the output result is limited to 25 rows" done? Which dbms are you using? Which query environment?

Comment: What database are you using? What software are you using to interact with your database? For example, Oracle database has [SQL Developer](https://www.oracle.com/database/sqldeveloper/) and SQL Server database has [SQL Server Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean limiting query result, depending on your database you can use some keywords.

For example, for SQL SERVER you can get only first 50 rows via the command below:

```
select top 50 * from yourTable;
```

But if you are limiting your output display via an editor/IDE, you need to check manual of it.